# Using pointers in c# to return array from an external function (xamarin.mac)

Tags: c#, pointers, xamarin

I have some c code which i didn't write which does some complicated things, and returns an array. I have been trying to use this code in a dynamic library in xamarin.mac to get this array from an extern function in my c# code, but with no success. I have read elsewhere that i should avoid using pointers in c# wherever possible, but I'm not sure how else i could do it.

My c# code is quite long but I'm using

```
[DllImport("librp_origin.dylib")]
        static extern IntPtr counter(int number);
```

to import the function from the dll, and

```
private IntPtr number;
partial void go(NSObject sender)
        {
            golabel.StringValue = "Doing the thing. . .";

            number = counter(2);

            golabel.StringValue = string.Format("Thing returned {0}", number);
        }
```

to attempt to access the array.

The c in the above is a simple example program which takes in an integer, and prints out a 20x20 array of that integer to the power x, and x increases each time. I know that printing out a whole pointer to the label is nonsense, but this is as close to the solution as i have. Any help whatsoever would be amazing !

Comment: What's the problem you're having? Converting `IntPtr` back to the array?

Comment: Yeah i think that was the problem, managed to get it fixed with a bit of help from google, sorry for the pointless question and thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i solved the problem in what i was doing, and i realise my question was quite vague. The main issue i had was i needed to use unsafe{} and Marshal.copy

The links i found most helpful were these:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_unsafe_codes.htm

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146635(v=vs.110).aspx

So i needed to retrieve the pointer as IntPtr and then convert it to an array to actually access the data in the way i was using it.